# javascript replacing escape chars

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all `\"` with `"` from a string that is returned from xml response in javascript.

For example: I have string `my \" string \" is messedup in \" xml`, the expected string is `my " string " is messedup in " xml`

I have tried  `strVariable= strVariable.replace("/\\\"/g", '"');`.  it does not work.
I have also tried  `strVariable= strVariable.replace("/\"/g", '"');` This also does not work.
Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
strVariable= strVariable.replace(/\\\"/g, '"');
```

Regex are consturcted without quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.split('\\"').join('"');
```

The code will replace all `\"` with `"`.

Edit : Sorry I forgot `\`

Edit : Changed the code as per comments

Comment: I did not downvote, but the syntax is wrong, this will result in a SyntaxError

Comment: I didn't downvote and I agree it's generally impolite to do so without comment. I suspect in this case it's because your string syntax is wrong in the argument to `.split()`.

Comment: Actually your solution is pretty clever! I would say a good non-regex solution!!

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the information. Now i fixed this issue. I usually depend on Array functions as they are very optimized and fast.

Comment: you are replacing `"\` with `"`, but the OP requested replacing `\"` with `"`

Comment: @bbuecherl haaa, thanks. Changed it. It's saturday evening ;) hope you understood.

Comment: no problem, look at the syntax of my comment above :D upvoted since it's a correct answer